# Run vmware workstation player in Azure vm

Tags: virtual-machine, vmware, azure

Is it possible to run vmware workstation player in a azure windows 10 vm machine? If no, then can I use azure unbuntu vm machine for this purpose?

Answer (score 1):

It probably is not possible with the newest version because Azure will be based on Hyper-V . However it *might* be possible based on some of the content in the following article.

https://communities.vmware.com/thread/634674

> I found only this solution :
>
> If you want to use vmware : use this command in powershell and reboot
> system:
>
> bcdedit /set hypervisorlaunchtype off
>
> If you to want use hyper-v:
>
> bcdedit /set hypervisorlaunchtype auto   Hyper-v and Vmvare still
> don't work together

Your second idea (using a separate Ubuntu VM) should work (but not to run VMware Player as that is the same issue as above).

Comment: Here is the real reason you are getting the error: "The reason that nested virtualization doesn't work is because our virtual machine monitor ("vmm", the 'hypervisor' part of the hypervisor) code was designed and optimized to do this, but Hyper-V monitor code is not. We actually test ESXi in Workstation (for linux) VMs in monster CI pipelines.

Our stack is obviously more mature, so when using the Hyper-V API's we had to make some compromises. We're working with MS to address the use-case, but we don't have a solid delivery date to communicate just yet."

Comment: While I quoted a VMWare employee, the very next page, indicates it is possible.

Comment: Nesting VMs is frequently troublesome, but I clarified my post to indicate the possibility .

Comment: @John I executerd powershell command, then restarted azure vm . I am getting same error again after installing workstation player("VMware Player and Hyper-V are not compatible.")

Comment: Yes. I think nesting this way is not really possible.

Comment: I am not sure if VMware Player will work nested. However, there are Azure instances, which support nested virtualization. You can definitely install Hyper-V on them, not sure about VMware Player though. 
https://www.starwindsoftware.com/blog/nested-virtualization-in-azure-with-starwind-vsan

Answer (score 0):

The Azure VM are already virtualized, and only in combination of HyperV
Therefore, there is no hardware accel available
But you may use qemu as an emulator ( so is not VMWare )
But the latest versions of WMWare 16 should ( need to test ) be integrated side by side with HyperV

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for late response but I found a tip to make it work.

Normally Azure is using Hyper-V to virtualize a VM but I found this tip.

```
How to enable VMware  working in Azure

1. Make sure you use a nested VT-x plan and not series F please use series E_v4 or D_v4 (eg,  E4ds v4)
2. Enable Windows hypervisor platform (not Hyper-V)
3. install VMware workstation player or pro
4. install VM and enjoy!

NOTICE: This tip can use with VMware Workstation 15.5.5+
limited for this: nested vt-x, countres cores, 3D is not working.
```